# Android Studio: ViewModel Exception

Tags: android, exception, viewmodel

I try creating a view model of a youtube tutorial, that's supposed to show all the entries from a database (but at this point it shoudl only display a Toast as there's no Recycler View yet)

I get the following exception when opening the activity:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tutorial/com.example.tutorial.Activity2}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.example.tutorial.EventViewModel
```

......

```
at com.example.tutorial.Activity2.onCreate(Activity2.java:23)
```

Class looks as following:

```
public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EventViewModel eventViewModel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);

        eventViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(EventViewModel.class);
        eventViewModel.getAllEvents().observe(this, new Observer<List<Event>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<Event> events) {
                Toast.makeText(Activity2.this, "thhthth", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

ViewModel Class:

```
public class EventViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    private EventRepository repository;
    private LiveData<List<Event>> allEvents;

    public EventViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        repository = new EventRepository(application);
        allEvents = repository.getAllEvents();
    }

    public void insert(Event event) {
        repository.insert(event);
    }

    public void update(Event event) {
        repository.update(event);
    }

    public void delete(Event event) {
        repository.delete(event);
    }

    public LiveData<List<Event>> getAllEvents() {
        return allEvents;
    }


}
```

How can I fix this? (still an Android beginner btw :^) )

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

This would work fine:

1.Go to your build.gradle(Module:app) and add this in the dependencies :

```
`implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$lifecycle_version"`
```

make sure to have the `def lifecycle_version = "2.2.0"` in your dependencies.
So it shoud look like this:

```
dependencies {

    def lifecycle_version = "2.2.0"  //make sure to have this 

    //Some implementations ...  

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'


    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$lifecycle_version" // make sure to have this too.

}
```

2.Go to your Activity (in your case it's the `Activity2`) and put this line:

```
eventViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this, ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(this.getApplication())).get(EventViewModel.class);
```

So your code should look like this:

```
public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EventViewModel eventViewModel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);

        eventViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this, ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(this.getApplication())).get(EventViewModel.class);
        eventViewModel.getAllEvents().observe(this, new Observer<List<Event>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<Event> events) {
                Toast.makeText(Activity2.this, "enjoy :)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

3.Run your app.

Answer (score 1):

Your viewModel extends AndroidViewModel. Use AndroidViewModelFactory:

```
yourViewModel = new ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory(getApplication()).create(YourViewModel.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

You must define "eventViewModel" in method **onCreate** and don't make a general variable.

```
public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);

        EventViewModel eventViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(EventViewModel.class);
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**because "ViewModelProviders" is deprecated, for java programmers, use this:100% gonna work**

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    noteViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this
            , ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(this.getApplication()))
            .get(NoteViewModel.class);

    noteViewModel.getAllNotes().observe(this, new Observer<List<Note>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<Note> notes) {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Onchange ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

**Go to your build.gradle(Module:app)**

```
def lifecycle_version = "2.2.0"
def room_version = "2.2.5"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:$lifecycle_version"
// LiveData
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:$lifecycle_version"
annotationProcessor "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version"

implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
```

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60857926/13614001

Android Studio - version 3.6.2

This worked for me.

Make sure you include the dependencies in the build.gradle(Module:app) and as well as the code changes.

More importantly "do the grade sync" after including the dependencies.

Comment: Hey its better to add the link as a comment because you are just pointing to a different answer. Otherwise, add your answer customizing it to the specific question, and then add the link as the source.